# String to DateTime in c#: 2018-05-10 10-AM

Tags: c#, datetime, datetime-format

I would like to convert the String "2018-05-10 10-AM" to a DateTime-Object. I tried everything, including this (is throwing an Exception):

```
var date = DateTime.ParseExact("values[0]", "yyyy-MM-dd HH-tt", 
System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Anybody knows what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Is `"values[0]"` a typo? You are passing in the wrong string... The date you show will parse fine with this code, apart from any times in the PM as demonstrated in @Soner's answer.

Comment: @DavidG I _really_ consider to delete my answer after your comment since it _can_ be parsed with `HH` specifier as well.

Comment: @SonerGönül No, it's still valid for times in PM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should [`hh` specifier](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings#the-hh-custom-format-specifier) instead of [`HH` specifier](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings#the-hh-custom-format-specifier-1) since your hour part is [12-hour clock](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/12-hour_clock) format, not [24-hour clock](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/24-hour_clock).

```
var date = DateTime.ParseExact("2018-05-10 10-AM", "yyyy-MM-dd hh-tt", 
                                  CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

And also as David [commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50305540/string-to-datetime-in-c-2018-05-10-10-am#comment87627309_50305540), you have a typo in your code. At least it should be like;

```
var date = DateTime.ParseExact(values[0], "yyyy-MM-dd hh-tt", 
                                  CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use something like this:

```
var date = DateTime.ParseExact("2018-05-10 10-AM", @"yyyy-MM-dd hh-tt", new CultureInfo("en-US"));
```

and in your own example:

```
var date = DateTime.ParseExact(values[0], @"yyyy-MM-dd hh-tt", new CultureInfo("en-US"));
```

note that don't put variables in quotations.